# Change of PC and can no longer publish Content

Tags: 2011, publishing

I have recently changed PC and ever since have been unable to publish content from Tridion to the local Tomcat server on my PC. I'm running Tridion 2011 and the error I get is:

> "Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_xxxxxxxxxxxxx.Content.zip using HTTPS"

The Tridion Deployer is installed on my system, but never starts up, so I don't see anything in the server console in my local server.  It's as if there is a network block.

Anyone else experienced this problem or have any tips for me?

Comment: Have you checked all of the pre-requisites are correct? I would, in particular, pay attention to the version of Java installed.

Comment: I have the same version of Java as on my old pc so I dont think that is the problem in this case.

Comment: Did you used to have a static IP and now don't or have a different IP? Check the configuration of your publication target. Also, if you're publishing via HTTPS, did you add the correct bindings to the deployer for HTTPS?

Comment: Have you checked the firewall and other security software on the PC?

Comment: Well, not 100% sure of the cause, but what I did to get it working again, was remove my version of putty (0.63) (my old pc where publishing worked was using version 0.60) and installed instead ExtraPuTTY from <http://download.cnet.com/ExtraPuTTY/3000-7240_4-10808581.html>.  Whether there is a bug in Putty (0.63) or whether its some local firewall setting causing the problems I'm not sure, but I'm just happy to finally get it working again.

Comment: Wait, tell us more. :-) Since only really Windows Servers are supported in delivery, you might be successfully running  on an unsupported setup. At least update "PC" with your OS and note how you're publishing, please.

Answer (score 4):

Is your Tridion license based on machine name?  This would explain it, maybe?  Invalid CD license.  Also, check your cd_core log file.

Answer (score 0):

in Addition to what @robtc mentioned, please also validate the no of cores in your license, because your new machine could have different no of cores.